# Change a Windows Server 2016 Machine From GUI to Core

Tags: windows-server

We have a Windows machine that when remoted into, the only thing that comes up is a command prompt. I'm under the impression that this machine is set to being Windows Core. I'm looking to do this to another one of our machines (Windows Server 2016) but the machine is already setup and running with the desktop GUI. Is it possible to change / retroactively put the machine back to Windows Core?

Answer (score 0):

install(GUI), unistall (core) Roles and Features  -> User Interfaces and Infrastructure